# как получить все курсы где категория = такая-то ? laravel

Tags: laravel

категория не как статическое поле а с помощью Relationship Voyager
Всем привет, 
2 связанные модели

```
class Course extends Model
{

    public function categories()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');

class Category extends Model
{

    public function courses()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
  }
}

$courses = Course::where('ВЫБРАННОЕ ПОЛЕ категория В АДМИНКЕ', $id)->orderBy('order')->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот таким вот образом:

```
Course::whereHas('category', function($query) use ($parameter){
  $query->where('some_parameter', $parameter)
})
->orderBy('order')
->get();
```

Comment: спасибо, решил так

$category = Category::where('slug', $id)->get();
 $paginator = $category[0]->courses()->orderBy('order')->paginate(9);

Comment: @junior ну это не то чтобы решение. Если у Вас $category[0] не будет, то будет ошибка.

Comment: ясно а почему в документации 
$roles = App\User::find(1)->roles()->orderBy('name')->get();
я не получаю вот так
$courses = Category::where('slug', $id)->courses()->orderBy('order')->get();

Comment: Метод courses может применяться к конкретной категории. Т.е. нужно ее сначала получить, например с помощью метода first():
 `$courses = Category::where('slug', $id)->first()->courses()->orderBy('order')->get();`

Comment: да спасибо, я только что это еще сам сделал, но все равно как вы говорите, если такой то категории не будет ошибка 
вот у меня к примеру http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/category/english
работает, а уже
http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/category/english1
Call to a member function courses() on null

не подскажите как решить правильно, чтобы если не существует такой категории в данном случае это english1 то чтобы переводило на туже страницу, просто там где должны выводится курсы их небыло и все.

редирект какой то?

Comment: @junior ну вообще, тут вылетает ошибка, потому что такой категории нет, но вы обращаетесь к модели, так, будто она есть. Вам либо нужно делать выборку категории с проверкой на ее наличие: 
`if($category = Category::where('slug', $id)->first()) {
  $cources = $category->courses()->get();
}` 

Либо сделать выборку, как я написал в ответе. Во втором случае вернет либо коллекцию, либо null. И уже исходя из результата, Вам нужно возвращать либо 404-страницу(если речь идет о таковой), либо сообщение об отсутствии результата(если у Вас API или админка)

Comment: вот так я сделал $paginator_one = Category::where('slug', $id)->first();  if (!$paginator_one) {    
            return abort(404);
        }